# How can I set multiple varibles to multiple elements using for loops

Tags: javascript

I tried this, but I noticed that with this, the variables are not even declared

```
let idArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let varArray = ['varOne', 'varTwo', 'varThree']
for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) { 
  varArray[i] = document.getElementById(idArray[i])
}
```

Comment: are the variables global?

Comment: if these are global, then `window[varArray[i]] = idArray[i]` would do the trick. Make sure, you've declared these variables before you make the assignments `var varOne, varTwo, varThree;`

Comment: first of all its `let` not `Let`

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I;m asking about `varOne` `varTwo` and `varThree` variables.

Comment: I think you need a dictionary

Comment: Sorry! I meant
varArray [i] = document.getElementById[idArray[i]

Comment: can probably use eval for this, eval(`${varArray[i]} = ${idArray[i]}`), then again not really sure what this code does

Answer (score 0):

I don't realy understand the purpose of your code, but if you want to make a copy of array (not a reference) :

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
let copy = [...arr]; // this is a copy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
let idArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let varArray = ['varOne', 'varTwo', 'varThree'];

varArray.forEach( (varName, index) => {
   globalThis[varName] = idArray[index];
});
```

Comment: I have edited my question, it was meant to be
    document.getElementById[idArray]

Answer (score 0):

```js
  let idArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    let varArray = ['varOne', 'varTwo', 'varThree'];
    let dict = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) { 
      dict[varArray[i]] = idArray[i]
    }
    
    console.log(dict)
```

or, if you want to use `varOne` or etc (**that is not recommended**):

```js
let idArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
    let varArray = ['varOne', 'varTwo', 'varThree'];
    for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) { 
      window[varArray[i]] = idArray[i]
    }
    
    console.log(varOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

As well not sure what you are trying to do exactly, maybe some more context would help. However, if you are trying to use a for-loop to populate the values of multiple variables according to the values within one of the arrays, why not just use an object?

e.g.

```js
const obj = {};
let idArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
let varArray = ['varOne', 'varTwo', 'varThree'];

for (let i = 0; i < idArray.length; i++) { 
  obj[varArray[i]] = idArray[i]; 
}
```

Otherwise, as already mentioned, you'd need to make the variables global and use window or global.